# Unable to write unit test cases for FHIR client api calls

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-dom, react-test-renderer

I hava component Componnent1 and inside the componentDidMount i am having the below code:-

```
const key1 = sessionStorage.getItem("key1");
    FHIR.oauth2
      .ready()
      .then((client) =>
        client.request("<url>/" + key1, {
          resolveReferences: [
          ],
          graph: true,
        })
      )
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
      })
      .catch(console.error);
```

And I am getting this error

● renders as expected

console.error internal/process/next_tick.js:68
TypeError: client.request is not a function
at _fhirclient.default.oauth2.ready.then.client (C:\Users\dbdeb\OneDrive\Desktop\patient-application\src\components\my-health-deatails.component\allergies.component\allergies.js:68:16)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

and my Test case is like:-

```
import { Component1} from "../component1"
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import FHIR from "fhirclient";
jest.mock('fhirclient', () => ({
    oauth2: {
        ready: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
            client: {
                request: jest.fn(() => { return { data: null } })
            }
        }))
    }
}));
test('renders as expected', () => {
    FHIR.oauth2.ready.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: { entry: '' } })
    render(<Component1></Component1>)
});
```

Comment: Have you mocked that class/object? Looks like it should return a promise. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue

Comment: Yes ive done it :-`jest.mock('fhirclient',()=>({
    ready:jest.fn(()=>Promise.resolve({data:null}))
}))`
But still I am getting the same error

Comment: The error, and your mock, is saying that it can't read a property `ready` of undefined, which means that `oath2` is undefined. The returned mock object should look something more like `{ oath2: { ready: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: null }) } }`.

Comment: And Now I am getting 
renders as expected

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'oauth2' of undefined


120 |   componentDidMount() {
      121 |     const patient_id = sessionStorage.getItem("patient_id");
    > 122 |     FHIR.oauth2
          |          ^
      123 |       .ready()
      124 |       .then((client) =>
      125 |

Comment: Looks like `FHIR` isn't defined or mocked. Can you update your question to include the imports for the component under test, and imports for the test file, and move the above error up to your question so it can be formatted and easier to read?

Comment: Now i updated the code and the error now getting a different error